# Enable SSL on Confluence with Docker on Synology

Tags: docker, https, confluence, nas, synology

I have a working installation of Confluence on Synology NAS using a Docker container.
I want to access the interface via https instead of just http. Can anyone please explain how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

It depends if your NAS is accessible from the internet or not. If it is, this is how to do it if we want to access Confluence through, for example, https://confluence.somecoolname.synology.me:8998

I wrote a full walkthough here: https://www.giuliomenna.net/confluence-on-synology-nas-via-docker-and-with-lets-encrypt-ssl/ but the part that interests you should be this:

1. Create a sub-domain for Confluence with the Reverse Proxy possibilities on your Synology NAS
2. Assign it a Let's Encrypt certificate

So:
From the DSM homepage, go to:

Control Panel > Application Portal

Select "Reverse Proxy" in the top menu.

Click on "Create" and a new window will appear.

Fill as follows (this is based on the example scenario we mentioned above)

Source

- Description: Confluence
- Protocol: https
- Hostname: https://confluence.somecoolname.synology.me
- Port: 8998
- Enable HSTS: check
- Enable HTTP/2: check

Destination

- Protocol: HTTP
- Hostname: localhost
- Port: (your Confluence's DockerLocal port)

Press "OK"

Next, assign it a Let's Encrypt certificate:

DSM > Control Pannel > Security

Select the "Certificate" tab

Click on "Add"

Select "Add a new certificate" and click Next

Select "Get a certificate from Let's Encrypt" and click Next (do NOT select "Set as default certificate")

- Domain name: confluence.somecoolname.synology.me
- Email: your email
- Subject Alternative Name: you may leave this empty

Click "Apply"

While still in DSM > Control Pannel > Security, select your newly created certificate and click on "Configure" (next to "Add")

The "Configure" tab appears.

In the column "Services" you will find https://confluence.somecoolname.synology.me:8998 - click on the dropdown under "Certificate" and select the confluence.somecoolname.synology.me (the certificate you have just created.)

Now confluence.somecoolname.synology.me:8998 is protected with an SSL certificate and when you will enter your password and username, it will be secured.

This is really the tip of the Iceberg though:

You will have to open port 8998 on your router (think of the security implications though, before you go ahead) and Tomcat will not be happy.